# Opening COM port greater than 9

Tags: api, vb6, serial-port

I have a VB6 program using commx.ocx to open ports.  The function works fine until the COM port is greater than 9.

There are articles stating that the same issue occurs when using Win32 API 'createfile'.  The fix when using createfile is to pass "\.\COM10" as the lpFileName parameter of createfile.

I still want to continue using commx.ocx.  Does anyone know how I can make it work if the COM is greater than 9?  I'm not sure how the method open() works on commx.ocx, but i know it relies on the PortNumber property that is a long data type, thus i cant pass \.\

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`commx.ocx` is not a native control in VB6. For help using it you should ask the authors.

Alternatively, you can use the [`MSComm32.ocx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) control that comes with VB6 where the [`CommPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259404%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property accepts any port number up to 16.

For any port higher than this, you will need to switch to the API or another 3rd party control that allows it.